# Why this CardMedia doesn't show image on resource folder?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I'm trying using a **Card** component with a photo using the **CardMedia** tag but I can't get the image shown at all. The image file is placed inside a created 'resources' folder.

I'm using **codesandbox.io** platform for coding this. Thank you all!

This is the **Card** implementation code in the **grid.js** file:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card'
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea'
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions'
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent'
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  media: {
    height: 140
  }
}

function Grid(props) {
  const { classes } = props
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="../resources/functional.png"
          title="Functional Programming"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h4" component="h4">
            Functional Programming
          </Typography>
          <Typography component="p">
            Functional Programming is a paradigm—a style of building the
            structure and elements of computer programs—that treats computation
            as the{' '}
            <b>
              evaluation of mathematical functions and avoids changing-state and
              mutable data
            </b>
            .
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          SEE MORE
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  )
}

Grid.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Grid)
```

And this is the folders' sctructure:

[image: folders' structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import your image first

```
import FunctionalImage from '../resources/functional.png';
```

then pass it like this :

```
<CardMedia image={FunctionalImage} />
```